reading web-side incoming X509 certificate from post request
Oct 6, still pending.  Although the suggestion of adding the [Authorize] did somehow get a step further, there was still nothing associated with the X509 certificate readable from the request anywhere.  Still unsure how to get and even recognize the certificate was even supplied.  Really appreciate some assist.
As just asked, "what server am I using"... At present, I dont specifically know what Visual Studio is using. I have not explicitly done any setup of IIS vs Kestrel.
Probably something simple, but I have looked and found many things about reading a client X509-certificate as part of a post. Here is the following scenario. VERY BASIC -- on my stand-alone machine, not a server anywhere, just my machine:
Using Visual Studio 2022. Web-side ASP.NET Core Web API project, support HTTPS, support certificate authentication.
Prepared self-signed HTTPS certificate for my machine for handling "localhost".
Simple controller method that returns a string.
Second project Visual Studio 2022 desktop app, C# .NET / WPF application.
WPF asks user for their PIN for their personal certificate.
Prepare a webrequest post to localhost.
Adds personal certificate to request and submits to localhost https site.
ASP.NET Core Web API gets request, but when I try to look for the certificate, nothing appears to be found for me to confirm it was even included. Below are applicable components of code.
From ASP.NET Core Web API:
Program.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Certificate;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();


builder.Services.AddAuthentication(
        CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCertificate(options =>
    {
        options.AllowedCertificateTypes = CertificateTypes.All;
        options.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;
        options.Events = new CertificateAuthenticationEvents
        {
            OnCertificateValidated = context =>
            {
                var claims = new[]
                {
                    new Claim(
                        ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier,
                        context.ClientCertificate.Subject,
                        ClaimValueTypes.String, context.Options.ClaimsIssuer),
                    new Claim(
                        ClaimTypes.Name,
                        context.ClientCertificate.Subject,
                        ClaimValueTypes.String, context.Options.ClaimsIssuer)
                };

                context.Principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(
                    new ClaimsIdentity(claims, context.Scheme.Name));
                context.Success();

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };
    });

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

Submit controller:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace MySampleNet.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class Submit : Controller
    {
        public string Index()
        {
            // not getting any client certificate from request posted
            var x = Request.HttpContext.Connection.ClientCertificate;
            return "Simple Return Text";
        }
    }
}

WPF application making the web request call:
    public void MyTesting()
    {
        var postURL = "https://localhost:7266/submit";

        // method prompts user to pick a certificate, enter PIN
        // validates PIN before adding to the web post below
        var cert = PickCACCertificate();
        var request = WebRequest.Create(postURL) as HttpWebRequest;

        // Set up the request properties.
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Accept = "*/*";

        request.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
        request.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        request.PreAuthenticate = true;
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;

        var webResponse = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

        var responseReader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());

        // try catch will handle any possible NULL response stream.
        var fullResponse = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
        webResponse.Close();
    }


No error is found in your code snippet, could you please share whether you are using kestrel or iis or some else for testing locally?

@FengzhiZhou, added to post above, not sure what VS2022 uses as default, and never heard of Kestrel, so I have not done any specifics of any setup.

You need to put [Authorize] attribute on either, MVC controller or controller action. ASP.NET core will not authenticate client and populate identity if this attribute is not presented.

Although the [Authorize] got me further, I still am unable to see anything associated with the attached X509 certificate.  Its like its not there, but know it has been attached to the request per the full sample code provided.

Any other suggestions?? I'm still stumped and cant see any cert info which is part of the post.

Please see this link for help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/certauth?view=aspnetcore-8.0#configure-your-server-to-require-certificates ...depending on what you are using(Kestrel or IIS) for testing. Also, Kestrel is configured by default in ASP.NET Core project templates.

I don't think you are configuring Kestrel to require a client certificate.
Checking the sample Program.cs you appear to be missing
builder.Services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(options =>
        options.ClientCertificateMode = ClientCertificateMode.RequireCertificate);
});

You can also configure it in your appsettings.json
"Kestrel": {
  "Endpoints": {
      "RequireClientCert": {
          "Url" : "https://localhost::7266",
          "ClientCertificateMode": "RequireCertificate"
      }
  }
}


Great start, getting closer, at least acknowledging cert.  I put option to "Allow" instead of required.  I dont want a request to fail outright if not as I will at least provide a message... hey, you need to vs fail.  However, I am getting message about my cert not within trusted chain.  Suggestions how to resolve trust?

Also, I do have the self-signed localhost certificate in the trusted structure from certlm.msc

Bit hard to say for sure, you can probably debug the received cert if you set it to not check the validity, it ought to pick up any certs in cert store. It also depends what your PickCACCertificate() method does to choose the cert.

With context of PickCACCertificate(), I know that works as I use that exact same to a different site we are sending to, just trying to go to new alternate site.

Super hard to say what is going wrong with trust issues without hands on keyboard. Can you check the framework / config for the different site that works - is it the same? Can you debug and view the received client certificate thumbprint and verify which store it is in. How are you generating the self-signed cert? Are you signing it with your own trusted root?

Appreciate considerations on my dilemma.  Generated as per Microsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/howto-create-self-signed-certificate and then moved into trusted certificates.  Again, this is for me locally and not the other server that I dont have access to, nor am hosting.

Assuming your self-signed cert is the one you select in your test app and is present in the Personal cert store it ought to work. I'm a little confused about the where this other server fits in?
